# Yii URL flow manager issue with Yii infinite scroll

Tags: php, jquery, yii, yii-url-manager

I have implemented project in Yii. I done Yii infinite scroll extensions. its working fine. but configure the URL management in Yii. its also working fine. am facing issue is. i am printing values is 10 per page Size. so, that values are repeating continues.

my config page is

```
                    'holidays/<name>'=>'recipe/index1',
            'calories/<name>'=>'recipe/index2',
                        ),
    'showScriptName'=>false,
```

above code  if i remove the . the URL will be show like this.. and lazy loader not repeating the values  ie working fine.

```
 recipe/index2/name/Chinese
```

i want to display like this

```
/Cuisine/Chinese
```

and also not reapting the page values. please help how to solve these issue

Answer (score 1):

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url if you didn't see this document: you can create an url pattern or write your own UrlRule class. For your example something like

```
array(
  '/Cuisine/<name:\w+>'=>'recipe/index2/name/<name>',
)
```

Comment: Hm - i've had the same issue and it worked for me. Seems you should provide more code.

Comment: Yii infinite lazy loader working for you wa?? after added custom url.. please tell. i searching last 3 weeks

Comment: Please provide some more code and we'll try to find a solution

Comment: 'urlManager'=>array(
   'urlFormat'=>'path',
              
                    //   'appendParams'=>true,
   'rules'=>array(
    
                                 '' => 'site/index',
                              //  'Home'=>'site/index',
     'Cuisine:<name\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'recipe/index3',    
   
                           'Cuisine/<name>'=>'recipe/index3',
            
       
                                  '2'=>'recipe/index1',
                     '3'=>'recipe/index2',
      'recipes/<name>'=>'recipe/recipeshow',                                
    'advancedsearch'=>'recipe/newadv',

Comment: Ok, so:
'/Cuisine/<param:\w+>' - your url pattern.
'recipe/index2/name/<param>' - your controller and action with param.

You should fix your url rules firstly - you have some mistakes,  slashes for example.

Answer (score 0):

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
           //  'useStrictParsing'=>true,
                //   'appendParams'=>true,
        'rules'=>array(
            // '<view:about>'=>'site/page',
                             '' => 'site/index',
                          //  'Home'=>'site/index',
            //'cuisine'=>'recipe/index3',
```

//               'Cuisine:/'=>'recipe/index3',
//                  'Cuisine/'=> 'recipe/index3',

```
                       'Cuisine/<name>'=>'recipe/index3',

              //     '1'=>'recipe/index3',
                              '2'=>'recipe/index1',
                    '3'=>'recipe/index2',
                           //'holidays/<name>'=>'recipe/index1',
                    //'calories/<name>'=>'recipe/index2',
            'recipes/<name>'=>'recipe/recipeshow',                                
            'advancedsearch'=>'recipe/newadv',
                           // 'advancedsearch/<name>'=>'recipe/advancesearch1',
              //  'search'=>'recipe/course',
                        //    '4'=>'recipe/course/',
            '5'=>'recipe/advancesearch1',
),
        //'appendParams'=>false,
    'showScriptName'=>false,
```

//       'caseSensitive'=>true,
        ),

Comment: i posted above configure code please check and tell me